# Sending a private message to a user?

Tags: support, status-completed, comments, chat

As I would tell something to a specific user, can I send him a message directly to not pollute the comment thread?

Comment: Only moderators can contact users to their associated/registered email, this is only used in serious situations and it is rare to happen. When this does happen all moderators are informed. As mentioned below users can create chat rooms if they have high enough rep. see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57537/how-do-i-contact-other-users

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you will see at [Any way to send a personal message to another user?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/431/any-way-to-send-a-personal-message-to-another-user) it is by design that there is no feature on Stack Exchange to facilitate private messaging between users.

Answer (score 8):

In addition to [PolyGeo's answer](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4710/64785), you could [create a chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/new) and invite that user to the chat and discuss with them in there.

While not *private*, you will be free to discuss in there without polluting the comment thread.  You could link to that new chat room in the comments so the user is aware of it.